# data synchronization between remote and local each with write

Tags: php, mysql, database, synchronization

I have a local database and a main database, both in mysql. The local db is being updated and the data being sent to the main db whenever there is internet. The main db is also being updated . How can i synchronize data  between the local site and the main server?

Comment: This is a fundamental problem of computing. You will likely have to start with timestamps on all data, but if the data is updated rapidly you will be facing a difficult task.

Comment: Does it mean that I will have timestamps on all the tables?

Comment: If two tables can be updated simultaneously on two databases, a time stamp is the only way to see in which order the data was created. Only tables with two sources of data need to be timestamped.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use one database instead two databases, in local development you may use ssh tunnel:

```
ssh -f -N -L 3333:192.127.48.160:5432 yoursite.com
```

Comment: The issue is that the network infrastructure is not good, thus the need for two databases that will need to be synchronized when there is internet availability